# Por qué no funciona al asignarle el prototipo?

Tags: javascript

Por qué no puedo asignarle el prototipo a `c` , de esta manera **para que contenga los métodos de la clase** `Array`

```
c.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype); // Aquí lo asigno
```

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',() => {
 var c = document.getElementsByClassName('clases'); 
  
 c.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);

 c.forEach(function(clase){
   
   console.log(clase.className);
 }); 
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<a class="clases">Enlace 1</a>
<a class="clases">Enlace 2</a>
<a class="clases">Enlace 3</a>
<a class="clases">Enlace 4</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porque con

```
Object.create(Array.prototype);
```

lo que haces es crear un objeto que tiene como prototipo el mismo que el de la clase `Array`. Por tanto con

```
c.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);
```

tienes un objeto `c` que tiene un atributo `prototype` un objeto que tiene como prototipo el prototipo de `Array`.

Piensa además que cuando creas una instancia de una clase, ésta instancia tiene el prototipo asignado en `<nombre_instancia>.__proto__` y no en `<nombre_instancia>.prototype`.

Realmente podrías hacer algo como lo siguiente y sería más sencillo:

```js
var c= document.getElementsByTagName('div');

c.forEach=Array.prototype.forEach;

c.forEach(e => 
 console.log(e));
```

```html
<div/>
<div/>
<div/>
```

Comment: También puedes utilizar `Array.from(c)` o `[...c]` a partir de ES6.

Answer (score 3):

Para consumir los metodo en el `prototype`, tienes que inicializar el objeto y el objeto `c` ya fue inicializado. No puedes modificiar el `prototype` de un objeto en runtime a menos que crees una nueva instancia del mismo:

```js
function carro(){
}

carro.prototype.correr = function(){
  console.log("corriendo");
}


var hyundai = new carro();
hyundai.correr();

hyundai.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);// ya el objeto hyundai fue creado, no puedes agregarle un prototipo en runtime
hyundai.push("2");
```

Si quieres "heredar" de algun otro objeto, tienes que especificarlo en la definicion del mismo:

```js
    function carro(){
    }
    
    // 'heredamos' de array en la definicion del objeto
    carro.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);
    
    carro.prototype.correr = function(){
      console.log("corriendo");
    }

    
    var hyundai = new carro();
    hyundai.correr();
    hyundai.push("2");
    
    hyundai.forEach(function(value){ console.log(value) });
```